# Java- have to model a circle

Tags: java

Okay so I don't know if any of you like helping homework at all, but I've gotten nowhere on this last part of a homework assignment. Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;

public class Circle {
    private Point center;
    private double radius;

    public Circle() {
        radius = 0;
        center = new Point(0, 0);
    }

    public Circle(Point c, double r) {
        radius = r;
        center = c;
    }

    public Point getCenter() {
        return center;
    }

    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public void setCenter(Point newCenter) {
        center = newCenter;
    }

    public void setRadius(double newRadius) {
        radius = newRadius;
    }

    public void drawCircle(Graphics g) {

    }

    public boolean doTheyIntersect(Circle other) {

    }
}
```

Okay so basically my teacher will use a program that makes circles on a drawing panel. He will use this to do that and then define where the circles are supposed to be. He required 6 specific methods on top of the constructors/fields. As you can see, I have done everything but the last 2 methods, one being a void and one a boolean.

The first one is supposed to enable graphics from java.awt, and the 2nd method is to check if they intersect. I literally think its one or 2 lines of code in each method I have not completed. The problem is that this is not an answer I can build towards, rather an answer I just have to try until I get it right, and I am LOST right now. So any pointers would be awesome. So anyways, in the "drawCircle" and the "doTheyIntersect" methods, I just need to know what will make them work. I literally just have to enable graphics in the first one, and then test the circles to see if they have a connecting point in the 2nd method. Tell me I'm a cheater or moocher all you want, but I'm LOST.

Comment: The intersecting point should not be too difficult, and you can Google that away.  The `drawCircle()` method might require some non-trivial code.

Comment: If you look at the javadocs for Graphics you will see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillOval(int,%20int,%20int,%20int) for drawOval

Comment: I would recommend sketching some circles and seeing if you can determine conditions for intersection (something to do with the distance between their centers).

Answer (score 1):

From the top of my head:

```
public void drawCircle(Graphics g) {
  g.drawOval(center.x+radius, center.y+radius, 2*radius, 2*radius);
}

public boolean doTheyIntersect(Circle other) {
  return other.getRadius() + radius > distance(center, other.getCenter());
}
```

The distance method is also quite easy.

Comment: I think you need `2*radius` as the width & height.